# Regexp: forbid some characters in a pre-defined category

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to check if a string is composed of any printable characters but no special symbols like: `?\/:"<>|*`. I'm now using `[[:print:]]` to match any printable characters, but have totally no idea how to forbid these special characters from printable category.

Any idea please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use negative lookahead assertion.

```
^(?!.*?[?\/:"<>|*])[[:print:]]+$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zU0cX2/3)

Comment: Could you give a full expression? I tried `\A(?![?\/:"<>|*])[[:print:]]+\z` but is not what I want. Thanks for your help!